# Conditional operator successfully compiled in windows but gives error in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, conditional-operator

Please help me reason out for the error I am getting with this statement, in Linux environment.

```
p_pAphErrorMessage->getSvc()?l_AphUpdateMessage->setSvc(p_pAphErrorMessage->getSvc()):0;
p_pAphErrorMessage->getObj()?l_AphUpdateMessage->setObj(p_pAphErrorMessage->getObj()):0;
```

This code is successfully compiled in windows but its giving error in Linux enviroment.

```
src/aph.cpp:7320: error: âl_AphUpdateMessage->AphMessage::setSvc(((AphUpdateMessage*)p_pAphErrorMessage)->AphUpdateMessage::<anonymous>.AphFidValuesMessage::<anonymous>.AphMessage::getSvc())â has type âvoidâ and is not a throw-expression
src/aph.cpp:7321: error: âl_AphUpdateMessage->AphMessage::setObj(((AphUpdateMessage*)p_pAphErrorMessage)->AphUpdateMessage::<anonymous>.AphFidValuesMessage::<anonymous>.AphMessage::getObj())â has type âvoidâ and is not a throw-expression
```

I investigated this a bit and suspect returning 0; could be the reason for it.
Can we use conditional operator in such a way to use it just for if not for else, eg,

```
c= a?a:/*DO NOTHING*/;
```

But, this way I am not getting any success in compilation. Any other recommended way to achieve it.

Comment: Why are you attempting to use the ternary operator purely for side effects? Why not just use `if`?

Comment: What compilers are you using? There's a good chance there's more different here than just "Windows" and "Linux".

Comment: @svk Not only is the ternary operator purely for side effects, but he really doesn't want the third part of it.  This screams out as abuse of the ternary operator.  As you say, just use `if`.

Comment: @ ALL, shouldn't this work and acceptable? as suggested by Mr Joachim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast the zero to `void`, like

```
condition ? expression : (void) 0;
```

The reason is that both the `setSvc` and `setObj` are declared as returning `void` (as seen in the error messages). This means the result of the expression where you call them is nothing. But the other "false" expression is an expression with a value. So the ternary expression have one branch that doesn't return a value and one branch that does return a value, which is not allowed. Casting the "false" expression to `void` makes both branches the same.

Comment: Can you please also explain the reason for it? It would be helpful for me in future.

Comment: "which is not allowed": unless the `void` is a throw expression.

Comment: Since I am getting all the answers here, one more to be answered.
what does this mean "is not a throw-expression"?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use the ternary operator this way, as it operates with 3 arguments:

```
expression1 : expression2 ? expression3
```

But you always can do:

```
c = a ? a : c;
```

Comment: This is a good way.. But shouldn't this will result in undesired  behavior if c is not initialized properly before. Thanks.

Comment: It's ok, if `c` is not initialised then nothing is changed. But yeah, some debuggers can warn you about using uninitialized variable.